# using lead() to modify next row data

Tags: sql-server, date, condition

So I have some data like this:

[image: 1]

And what I would like to do is modify the WorkDate using the following logic

```
if lead(EndTime) = StartTime
then lead(WorkDate) = WorkDate
```

So for example R3 WorkDate should be 2021-06-03 00:00:00.000, because R3.StartTime = R2.EndTime and so R3.WorkDate should be R2.WorkDate.

I have the following query written:

```sql
select 
CASE
WHEN LEAD(StartTime) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) = EndTime
THEN CASE
    WHEN LEAD(WorkDate) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) = WorkDate
    THEN WorkDate
    ELSE Dateadd(day, -1, LEAD(WorkDate) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime))
    END
ELSE
    WorkDate
END
from #tmp
```

The issue with it is that it is 'modifying' the current row data (WorkDate), rather than the leading row data. I get the following output:

[image]

Which is ultimately the exact same as before. Any guidance on how I'd go modifying the leading row?

Comment: Consider rethinking your logic in the inverse of it's current from. That is, to use `LAG()` to reference the prior row.

Comment: Take a look at how to create a [mcve], then add the DDL for your table along with some sample `INSERT INTO...` statements with data.  And, please, take the [tour] 